# Дублирование записей в MS SQL Server

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

У меня имеется 2 класса сущностей, первый класс:

```
public class Vnz
{
    [Key]
    public int Id_Vnz { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(50)]
    public string NameVnz { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(20)]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Deckrib { get; set; }
    public string History { get; set; }
    public List<Vidilena> vidilenas { get; set; }
}
```

и второй класс:

```
public class Vidilena
{
    [Key]
    public int Id_Vid { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(50)]
    public string NameVid { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string Shifr { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(50)]
    public string Zaviduvach { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(20)]
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
    public string Decrib { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Vnz Vnz { get; set; }
}
```

контекст следующий:

```
class StudentContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Vnz> Vnzs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Vidilena> Vidilenas { get; set; }
}
```

при добавлении данных Vnz в таблицу всё работает нормально, но когда я добавляю данные в Vidilena, то дублируются данные Vnz(создается копия):

```
readonly StudentContext db = new StudentContext();
Vidilena vid = new Vidilena()
{
    Decrib = tbDescrib.Text,
    NameVid = tbName.Text,
    Shifr = tbShifr.Text,
    Zaviduvach = tbZaviduvach.Text,
    Telephone = tbTelephone.Text,
    Vnz = db.Vnzs.Where(d=>d.Id_Vnz.Equals(VnzId)).FirstOrDefault()
};
await comand.VidilAddAsync(vid);
```

вот код метода:

```
public async Task VidilAddAsync(Vidilena vidilena)
{
     using (StudentContext db = new StudentContext())
     {
         try
         {
             db.Vidilenas.Add(vidilena);
             await db.SaveChangesAsync();
             Boxes.Information("Успішно додано!");
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             Boxes.Error(ex.Message);
         }
     }
 }
```

как убрать дубликаты?

Comment: Вы заполняете поле `Vnz` в таблице `Vidilena`? Может из него берутся дубликаты?

Comment: Закомментируйте строку `Vnz = db.Vnzs.Where(d=>d.Id_Vnz.Equals(VnzId)).FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: а как тогда будет идти связь навигационных свойств? Я этой строкой привязываю связью один к многим (это же ссылка на другую таблицу)

Comment: Нужно создать поле VnzId - которое почему-то вы не создали ранее. Также вам нужен пустой конструктор Vnz который заполнит `vidilenas = new List<Vdilena>();`.

Comment: VnzId нужно создать в классе Vidilena?

Comment: Да, в этом классе. Конструктор тоже важен.

Comment: а как тогда потом доставать данные привязанные через этот VnzId (раньше я добавлял простой объект через навигационное свойство), тут разве не нарушается целостность данных?